# jQuery animate with dynamic properties, throws error Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I've written an animate function that I can use passing different properties which I'd like to animate but for some reason IE11 doesn't like it.

Researching the error I thought it might be a trailing comma or reserved keyword that I shouldn't be using but I've tried everything.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
function animate(id, propertyName, propertyValue, propertyEasing, propertyDuration) {

    $('#' + id).stop().animate({
      [propertyName]: propertyValue // THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE PROBLEM
    }, {
        duration: propertyDuration,
        easing: propertyEasing,
        queue: false
    });

}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecL39bcv/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following code

```
var animation = {};
 function animate(id, propertyName, propertyValue, propertyEasing, propertyDuration) {
   animation[propertyName] = propertyValue;
        $('#' + id).stop().animate(
          animation, {
            duration: propertyDuration,
            easing: propertyEasing,
            queue: false
        });
    }   
animate ('test', 'height', '600px', 'easeOutQuint', 6000);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks - that works - can you explain the difference between mine and yours please?

Comment: just passed propertyName and propertyValue as an object to animate function.